# How to get firefox to remember URLs visited in a frame across browser restarts?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-history, frames

I've written a greasemonkey script that modifies craigslist search results to appear in two frames, a frame on the left with the results listed and a frame on the right to display each posting if clicked on from the left frame (I modify the URL of each result to say target="rightframe").

The problem I have is that the 'visited' status of URLs on the result frame seems to be lost when I restart the browser.  That is, when I click on a link in the left frame, the link appears in the 'visited' style, and this persists when I reload the page.  However, if I restart the browser and visit the page again, then that link no longer appears in the 'visited' style.  This makes it hard to keep track of which postings I've already seen :(.

The reason I believe the frames are causing the problem is that if I click on a search result link on craigslist without the greasemonkey script, then the 'visited' status persists across browser restarts.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.  There is a [bug tracking this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=477882).  If you were not in Greasemonkey and were an actual add-on, you could call the proper history API and add it manually if you wanted.

Comment: And to add more to this - it should be fixed in whatever version of Firefox is released after Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't address your question directly, but since you said the link visited status is remembered when not added to frames, have you tried just manipulating the page using `<div />`s with their `overflow` property set to "scroll"?

This would ensure that the links don't have to change their context which may fix your problem.